# Mysql Display titles of books from authors who have more than 1 book

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a table of `Books`, Each book has `2 fileds` that are revelant now: `Title` & `Author`, How can I display the titles of the books from authors who have more than 1 book? I've tried

```
SELECT Title, Author, COUNT(Author) AS Books FROM BOOK 
GROUP BY Author HAVING COUNT(Author) >= 2;
```

but this only gives me 1 title per author, the author and the amt of books this author has. e.g

```
The Sun Also Rises | Hemingway | 2
Foundation         | Asimov    | 2
```

and so forth.

How to solve? Subquerys can aslo be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine in a subquery the authors, who have at least 2 books, then get the list of books for them:

```
SELECT book.Title, book.Author
FROM book
INNER JOIN (SELECT Author FROM BOOK GROUP BY Author HAVING COUNT(Author) >= 2) t
ON book.Author=t.Author;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `group_concat` like that :-

```
SELECT group_concat(Title) as Title, Author, COUNT(Author) AS Books 
FROM BOOK GROUP BY Author HAVING COUNT(Author) >= 2;
```

[Run this query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ee5f/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.title,b.author,c.cnt FROM books AS b INNER JOIN
(SELECT author,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM books GROUP BY author) AS c
ON b.author = c.author
WHERE c.cnt > 1;
```

Works on any database system, not just mysql.

Comment: Regarding your edit suggestion: count(fieldname) does not always return 1. It counts all non-null values within that field, even if a value is repeated.